# Stream: Filter on children, return the parent

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Assume a class `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass {

    private final Integer myId;
    private final String myCSVListOfThings;

    public MyClass(Integer myId, String myCSVListOfThings) {
        this.myId = myId;
        this.myCSVListOfThings = myCSVListOfThings;
    }

    // Getters, Setters, etc
}
```

And this Stream:

```
final Stream<MyClass> streamOfObjects = Stream.of(
        new MyClass(1, "thing1;thing2;thing3"),
        new MyClass(2, "thing2;thing3;thing4"),
        new MyClass(3, "thingX;thingY;thingZ"));
```

I want to return every instance of `MyClass` that contains an entry `"thing2"` in `myCSVListOfThings`.

If I wanted a `List<String>` containing `myCSVListOfThings` this could be done easily:

```
List<String> filteredThings = streamOfObjects
        .flatMap(o -> Arrays.stream(o.getMyCSVListOfThings().split(";")))
        .filter("thing2"::equals)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But what I really need is a `List<MyClass>`.

This is what I have right now:

```
List<MyClass> filteredClasses = streamOfObjects.filter(o -> {
     Stream<String> things = Arrays.stream(o.getMyCSVListOfThings().split(";"));
     return things.anyMatch(s -> s.equals("thing2"));
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But somehow it does not feel right. Any cleaner solution than opening a new `Stream` inside of a `Predicate`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, I recommend you to add extra method to `MyClass` `public boolean containsThing(String str)`, so you can transform you code like this:

```
List<MyClass> filteredClasses = streamOfObjects
  .filter(o -> o.containsThing("thing2"))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now you can implement this method as you want depends on input data: splitting into `Stream`, splitting into `Set`, even searching of `substring` (if it's possible and has sense), caching result if you need.

You know much more about usage of this class so you can make right choice.

Comment: Looks cleaner. In the end `containsThing` in my case will probably still be something much like the code in the question, but at least separation of concerns is enforced. Anyway, are you aware of any generic technique to simplify this kind of scenario? Assume that I have a `Stream` of `MyClass1`, that holds a list of `MyClass2` that holds a list of `MyClass3` that holds a `String` with things. If I wanted to filter based on the string of things and return a `List<MyClass1>` how would you do it?

Comment: Indeed. Your original solution is too tightly coupled. Adding an inspeciton method (`contains()`) decouples the interface (outward appearance) from the inner details of the `MyClass`.

Comment: It's better to change `filter(o -> o.containsThing("thing2"))` to `filter(o -> o.containsThing(";thing2;"))`.

Comment: @walsh what about "thing2;thing3;thing4" ?  may be by adding ; as prefix and suffix to o object then you can do it

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use a pattern matching that avoids the split-and-stream operation:

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(^|;)thing2($|;)");
List<MyClass> filteredClasses = streamOfObjects
    .filter(o -> p.matcher(o.getMyCSVListOfThings()).find())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Since the argument to `String.split` is defined as regex pattern, the pattern above has the same semantic as looking for a match within the result of `split`; you are looking for the word `thing2` between two boundaries, the first is either, the beginning of the line or a semicolon, the second is either, the end of the line or a semicolon.

Besides that, there is nothing wrong with using another Stream operation within a predicate. But there are some ways to improve it. The lambda expression gets more concise if you omit the obsolete local variable holding the Stream. Generally, you should avoid holding Stream instances in local variables as chaining the operations directly will reduce the risk of trying to use a Stream more than one time. Second, you can use the `Pattern` class to stream over the resulting elements of a `split` operation without collecting them all into an array first:

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile(";");
List<MyClass> filteredClasses = streamOfObjects
    .filter(o -> p.splitAsStream(o.getMyCSVListOfThings()).anyMatch("thing2"::equals))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile(";");
List<MyClass> filteredClasses = streamOfObjects
    .filter(o -> p.splitAsStream(o.getMyCSVListOfThings()).anyMatch(s->s.equals("thing2")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that you could also rewrite your original code to

```
List<MyClass> filteredClasses = listOfObjects.stream()
    .filter(o -> Arrays.asList(o.getMyCSVListOfThings().split(";")).contains("thing2"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now, the operation within the predicate is not a Stream but a Collection operation, but this doesn’t change the semantic nor the correctness of the code…

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you have three options.

1) look for particular entry in the String without spliting it - still looks messy

```
List<MyClass> filteredClasses = streamOfObjects
              .filter(o -> o.getMyCSVListOfThings().contains(";thing2;"))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

2) map twice - still messy

```
List<MyClass> filteredClasses = streamOfObjects
              .map(o -> Pair<MyClass, List<String>>.of(o, toList(o.getMyCSVListOfThings()))
              .filter(pair -> pair.getRight().contains("thing2"))
              .map(pair -> pair.getLeft())
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where toList is a method that will convert String to List

3) create additional field - method I'd suggest

Extend class MyClass - add field to the class

```
List<String> values;
```

And initialize it in the constructor:

```
public MyClass(Integer myId, String myCSVListOfThings) {
    this.myId = myId;
    this.myCSVListOfThings = myCSVListOfThings;
    this.values = toList(myCSVListOfThings);
}
```

And then in the stream simply:

```
List<MyClass> filteredClasses = streamOfObjects
          .filter(o -> o.getValues().contains("thing2"))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course field values can be initialized in LAZY mode during first getValues method call if you want.

Comment: `;thing2;` may fail in some corner cases (e.g., `thing2` is the first or last string), but I got your point. Other two options works fine and even option 1 is possible with some regex magic. Anyway, can you have a look on my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38973410/stream-filter-on-children-return-the-parent/38973554#comment65300747_38973554) above? I'm worried about how those techniques scale in a real world scenario where the information to be filtered may be nested several objects bellow the object that I want to return (i.e., great-grandchild).

Comment: Are you familliar with Visitor and Strategy Pattern? In order to create a generic solution I'd combine both. Based on what you are looking for in the object and class of the start object (strategy) I would create different Visitor object which I would then pass as an argument to your class method. Visitor would determine if your object meets the criteria. Inside the Visitor object you could enclose the whole logic of checking the objects of your classes and their children / grandchildren etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the issue, [Getting only required objects from a list using Java 8 Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132387/getting-only-required-objects-from-a-list-using-java-8-streams/44054853#44054853), posted a year earlier. I think the solution I left there is applicable here.

There's a library called com.coopstools.cachemonads. It extends the java stream (and Optional) classes to allow caching of entities for later use.

The solution can be found with:

```
List<Parent> goodParents = CacheStream.of(parents)
            .cache()
            .map(Parent::getChildren)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(Child::getAttrib1)
            .filter(att -> att > 10)
            .load()
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where, parents is an array or stream.

For clarity, the cache method is what stores the parents; and the load method is what pulls the parents back out. And If a parent does not have children, a filter will be needed after the first map to remove the null lists.

More specifically, for your issue:

```
List<Parent> goodParents = CacheStream.of(streamOfObjects)
    .cache()
    .map(o -> o.getMyCSVListOfThings().split(";"))
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .filter("thing2"::equals)
    .load()
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

This library can be used in any situation where operations need to be performed on children, including map/sort/filter/etc, but where an older entity is still needed. There may be more lines than some of the other answers, but each line is very clean and straight forward.

Please let me know if this answer is helpful.

The code can be found at https://github.com/coopstools/cachemonads or can be downloaded from maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.coopstools</groupId>
    <artifactId>cachemonads</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

(or, gradle, com.coopstools:cachemonads:0.2.0)